# Retrieve firebase data from binding ListView Xamarin Forms

Tags: listview, firebase-realtime-database, xamarin.forms, binding

I have a listview where I retrieve data from firebase with an helper and show it by binding them in .xaml, like that:

the helper:

```
public class FirebaseHelper
public async Task<List<Books>> GetAllBooks()
        {
            return (await firebase
              .Child("Books")
              .OnceAsync<Books>()).Select(item => new Books
              {
                  Title = item.Object.Title,
                  Author = item.Object.Author,
                  Genre = item.Object.Genre,
                  Cover  = item.Object.Cover
              }).ToList();
        }
```

the page.xaml.cs

```
public List<Books> libriall;

protected async override void OnAppearing()
        { 
            base.OnAppearing();
            bookall = await firebaseHelper.GetAllBooks();
            listbook.ItemsSource = bookall;
        }
```

and a part of the listview listbook in the .xaml file:

```
<Label 
       TextColor="#33272a"
       Text="{Binding Title}"
       x:Name="bTitle"/>
```

Ok now I put a Button in the ViewCell and I want to get the book title and use it in a PostAsync, so I basically need to get the single title book and put it in a string.

Already created a method like that in the helper:

```
public async Task<string> getTitle()
        {
            return (await firebase
              .Child("Books")
              .OnceAsync<Books>()).Select(item => new Books
              {
                  Title = item.Title
              }).ToString();
        }
```

But I don't know how to link books properties to the single viewcell they are displayed with the binding, any idea?

Comment: if `GetAllBooks` retrieves the title, why do you need another method `getTitle` to also get the title?

Comment: getAllBooks returns a List, GetTitle returns a string instead

Comment: Yes, but the list contains a list of Book, and each Book already has a Title property.  Why do you need to retrieve it again, instead of just pulling it from the Book that you already have?  You are clicking a row in your list, you just want to get the title of the book for that row?

Comment: I only want the title from the row I'm interacting with, if I use GetAllBooks I get the list of all the books with their properties while I only want a string.

Comment: you **do not need** to call `GetAllBooks` again, you **already** have all of that data in the `ItemsSource`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you **do not need** to get the data from your service again, you already have it in the `ItemsSource` for your list

```
void ButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
  Button btn = (Button)sender;

  // the BindingContext of the Button will be the Books
  // object for the row you clicked on 
  var book = (Books)btn.BindingContext;

  // now you can access all of the properties of Books
  var title = book.Title;
}
```